# Implement SMS sending functionality in ASP.NET C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sms, sms-gateway

I have a requirement to send SMS to users from my ASP.NET web application. First I want to know whether **any free service is available** to do this? When I googled I got lots of links (even from stackoverflow) related to sending sms via way2sms.com 160by2 and such sort of things but unfortunately not even a single thing worked. I tried with the SmsClient.dll and ended up with the same story again.

I would like to get a very reliable reply from someone who has **implemented the same and how it was done** since now itself I have spend a lot of time googling and trying some sample codes got from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had implemented a project where SMS text was generated after user selects some text and forwarded it to mobile numbers fetched from database.

The SMS gateway provider gave us a URL in which the SMS text and the mobile numbers were embedded as parameter values , something like below

```
string url =@"http://10.10.10.10/id=ourId&password=xyz&message="+smsText+"&mobileNum="+num[i];
```

This string string contained url which was called using [**WebClient**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient) class

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
client.DownloadString(url);   
}
```